# md5 hash login with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, hash, passwords, md5

I was given an excel file with about 450 username and passwords (the passwords are encoded with MD5 hash)
How can I put this excel (.xls) file into my MySQL database and on the website (php side) how can I check if the user entered password is the correct password (I know nothing about hashing a password with MD5 or any hash-sequence for that matter)

Comment: Usual question: what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.- You can export an excel file as a CSV file.
2.- Use [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/) to import to your site a CSV file.
3.- Checking passwords:

```
if (md5($_POST['user_password']) == $db['user_password'])
{
    echo 'welcome back bro!'
}
```

Comment: (It won't let me accept the question until 4 more minutes from now so that's why I'm waiting incase you were wondering :) haha)

Comment: Nice, THX.- The md5 is a one-way encryption technique, it's impossible systematically decrypted (you can use brute force techniques but that is the same for all encryption system). So be happy. :)

Answer (score 2):

the md5 password may be "salted" to provide extra security.

If not salted:

- ?php md5(ClearTextPassord) == $passwordInExcel

If salt, this salt may etiher be global (same for all accounts), or partly individual, (some account-data is provided when calculationg the hash.

Example:

- Global: `<?php md5(onceTypedPassword . $globalSalt)`
- Global and individual: `<?php oncedTypedPassword . $globalSalt . $userRec['Firstname'])`
- ..other ways are possible..

If hash is salted you NEED the salt.

Comment: Yes, good point. But he said: `450 username and passwords` not salt involved.

Comment: doesn't hurt to have this mentioned either.. and md5 hashed passwords are not excactly secure... depending on what this 450 users are.. he he might want to consider salting anyways..

Answer (score 2):

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-phpexcel/ will help you with storing the passwords from the excel file to the mysql database, and [md5 documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) is pretty helpful.

You can fetch the password for a given username from the db and check with something like this:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string( $username_user_gave )
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' LIMIT 1;";
$result = mysql_query( $query ) or die('Could not perform query');
if( mysql_affected_rows != 1 ){
    // user not found
    }
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
$stored_password = $row['password'];
$given_password = md5( $password_user_gave );
if( $stored_password == $given_password ){
    //everything ok
    }
else{
    //incorrect password
    }
```