# Create login with PHP, MySQL, and MD5

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, hash, md5

**Issue has been resolved. Thank you to all whom posted and helped me out. The column type was to short (varchar(25)) - I extended it and was able to login. Everyone's comments were appreciated.**

I am having some issues when I try to log in using a test account I created. I am trying to make my own CMS. Right now I have the register page complete and working on the login page. I have MD5'd the user's password on register. When I go to try and login using this account the hash generated on the login page NEVER matches the hash stored in my SQL database.

Here is my PHP code and MySQL query:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['password']);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM records WHERE username='".$username."'") or die(mysql_error());  
$result= mysql_fetch_array( $query );

if($result[0] == $username) {

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM records WHERE username='".$username."'") or die(mysql_error());
        $result = mysql_fetch_array( $query );
        $passHash = md5($password);

        echo "Hash: ".$passHash."<br/>";
        echo "User's hash: ".$result[0];

        if($result[0] == $passHash) {
            echo "XXXXX: WIN";
        }
        else {
           echo "fail";
        }
```

I have an account called "alex" the MD5 that was generated on the register page is "1c13465e24d91aca4d3ddaa1b" the MD5 hash generated on the login page is "1c13465e24d91aca4d3ddaa1bc3e7027"

Here is my registration page code:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['password']);
$md5_pass = md5($password);
mysql_real_escape_string(mysql_query("INSERT INTO records (username, password, ) VALUES('$username', '$md5_pass' ) ") or die(mysql_error()));
```

What am I doing wrong? I have been searching on here and looked at:

[md5 hash login with php and mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343807/md5-hash-login-with-php-and-mysql)

but no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you post the code that enters the data in the DB?

Comment: Have you tried $password = $_REQUEST['password']; instead of $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['password']);
 ???

Comment: Sure, look at my original post!

Comment: probably the length of field in your database is lower than the length of md5 values, varchar(50) is an option

Comment: Most likely the column data type for password is VARCHAR(25), tho your doing the whole login script wrong, also md5 is not secure, like **wicked** as the password.

Comment: I'm fully aware of md5's encryption. I am developing this as an internal system for my fraternity which only the brothers will know about. I am not really worried about one of them trying to try and SQL inject the site or anything but I suppose I cal always SALT the password.

Comment: @user1421248 md5 and encryption should never be in the same sentence let alone the same line...

Comment: Nope never user $_REQUEST['password'] on its own, you're leaving a backdoor to SQL Injection attacks this way. Geophoenix could be right. Change the password column type to varchar(32) and see if it works. Although I would suggest not using md5 and to use sha1 or even sha256/512 if you're paranoid about security. Collision attacks on md5 have been found and they are pretty easy to accomplish.

Comment: @ConstantineLoukas thank you, I will try extending the column type. I'm a beginner at PHP and MySQL so any tips is appreciated as another user below suggested.

Comment: It took me all of 1 second to input the hash into google to find its value.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone It's a test account. Congrats for copying and pasting a hash into Google for a word that is in the dictionary. I am only testing the login as of right now. Therefore I created a crappy account for testing purposes. As I've already said I am new at this. I read your comment about extending the length. No need to keep pestering me about the lame password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely the column that stores the password hash is too short, e.g. `VARCHAR(25)`.
Make it bigger: `CHAR(32)` or `BINARY(16)`.
See also:

- [What data type to use for hashed password field and what length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247304/mysql-what-data-type-to-use-for-hashed-password-field-and-what-length)
- [Best practices for efficiently storing md5 hashes in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326584/best-practices-for-efficiently-storing-md5-hashes-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use single SELECT statement to get your User data:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM records WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".md5($password)."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Second point - don't use mysql_* functions - they are outdated. Switch to PDO or MySQLi.

There might be space in your DB pass...

Comment: I'll have to look into MySQLi. MySQL and PHP together is new for me as I've been trying to self teach myself it. Thank you sir for the tip